How to go back to a the original sheet after running a macro?
I am learning VBA through experimentation and online research. Please let me know if there is anything to improve or remove from my current tester code which is working.
I just want to reduce any waste / lines that wouldn't be needed. Any advise will be helpful.
resource: https://forum.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/82720-store-current-sheet-name-as-variable/
Sub Test_return_from_start()

Dim WSD As Worksheet
Dim DataSheetName As String

Set WSD = ActiveSheet
DataSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

'start of actions wanted to be done
Sheet7.Select    
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "test"

'returning back to the original sheet
Sheets(DataSheetName).Activate

End Sub


If you get rid of the .Selects you will not need to "Return" to the original sheet: Sheet7.Range("B2").Value = "test"  Then just use WSD. as a prefix for any "work" on the original sheet.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

You don't need to select a cell to be able to modify the value.
Instead of using ActiveSheet/ActiveCell you can use the properties/methods of the worksheet object to directly change a worksheet.
Looking at the Project Explorer in the VBA IDE, there will be an entry for every worksheet you have. Each entry is ObjectName (SheetName).
ObjectName can be used as a reference to the worksheet (like Sheet7 in your code), if worksheets are not added to your workbook then its fairly safe to use these, you can also create your own references (similarly to WSD in your example).
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 

Your code example can be simplified to one line.
Sub Example()
Sheet7.Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "test"
End Sub

You could also create a Range Object if you were going to perform multiple tasks on that range/cell.
Sub Example()
Dim R As Range
Set R = Sheet7.Range("B2")
R.FormulaR1C1 = "test"
R.Interior.ColorIndex = 7 ' Set Background Color
End Sub

